# Java 21 Jwts parser() is deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to learn the Spring Security part and use a JWT token with Spring using the 'Jwts' library 0.12.5.

I was following a tutorial which presented this way:

```
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
    return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseSignedClaims(token)
            .getBody();

    }

private Key getSignInKey(){
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}
```

I saw the fact that 'getBody', 'parseSignedClaims' and 'setSigningKey' were deprecated, and I have tried to adapt to this:

```
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
    return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseSignedClaims(token)
            .getPayload();
}

private Key getSignInKey(){
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}
```

But I still use the 'setSigningKey'. I saw some old questions from the stack, but all of them contain deprecated parts. What is a better way to do it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you read the javadocs?  They give alternatives for the various deprecated methods.  For example, the javadoc says that `setSigningKey` should be replaced with `verifyWith`.

Comment: You might also want to check the spelling of your method names.  You are calling `setSigningKey` with a key returned by a method called `getSignInKey`.  But a signing key is not a sign-in key.  Signing and sign-in are different concepts.  Check your spelling, and/or that you don't have the concepts mixed up.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you I modified those thinks, I wrote the names of the methods as in the tutorial because it was the first time when I see it. I will read the documentation carefully next time.

Comment: Well apparently, the tutorial needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get claims

```
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
 return Jwts.parser()
.verifyWith(getSignInKey())
.build()
.parseSignedClaims(token)
.getPayload();
}
```

to generate token

```
 public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
  
    return Jwts.builder()
            .subject(userDetails.getUsername())
            .issuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() +    TOKEN_VALIDITY))
            .signWith(getSignInKey())
            .compact();
}
```

Comment: to generate token    return Jwts.builder()
                .subject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .issuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TOKEN_VALIDITY))
                .signWith(getSignInKey())
                .compact();